# Ruby on Rails: Check_boxes for each item in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to render simple check_boxes in a list of results so users can select on which of these results to get additional content for.

Example model setup (names changed):

```
UserRequest has_one :response
Response has_many :individual_results
IndividualResult has_one :contact_info
```

In the `UserRequestsController` I have a show action, which shows the user_request (duh), response, and its individual_results in a table.

The user should be able to select items (= contact_info) to request additional content for those. For some reason I don't manage to render the check_boxes after days of trying. Basically, I don't really understand where and how to store the array of selected `contact_infos` and how to pass it to the method that then gets the additional content.

My attempt was:

- Create a `ContactInfosController` (didn't exist before, the user was only creating and showing her requests up to now, so contact_info was "model only" before)
- Create a method `request_content(contact_infos)` (as post, to pass the user-selected contact_infos to. If I were to make it Restful, it would probably be "edit/update")
- Add the form with check_boxes `search_request#show`

My `search_request/show.html.erb`:

```
<tbody>
  <% if @response %>
    <% form_for @contact_infos, url: contact_infos_request_content_path(@contact_infos) do |form| %>
      <% @response.individual_results.each do |result| %>
        # result.foo, ...
        # result.contact_info.bar
        <%= form.check_box "contact_info", "contact_info.request_content?", "true", "false %>
      <% end %>
      # form.submit
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

As it didn't work, I also had to declare the instance variable `@contact_infos` in `RequestsController#show` as `@contact_infos = @response.individual_results.map { |r| r.contact_info }`

Now, it fails at the check_box with "undefined method `merge'". Also, not sure how the params would be passed? I feel I went seriously "off the rails" and probably screwed up the design with this as it seems way too complicated...

Would anybody be so kind and help me get into the right direction, e.g., how would you pass the response to a method to request additional information? Read tons online but somehow couldn't apply it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is from 4.2, but I doubt it would have changed in latest. https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Comment: can you post also your corresponding controller code and also the code where `merge` method is being called

Comment: You said "names changed" for your example model setup, but as they are (if it remotely resembles your data) it's a very awkward data model. I'd need more information on the actual problem being solved to give good advice, right now the data model feels inverted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments... I feel kind of embarrassed, probably there is something wrong with my code :( It's only my fourth app, all hobby projects. Basically, all I'm trying to do be able to select items that are rendered in a show view, but my main problem is defining the instance variable for the form and passing it "somewhere", similar to https://medium.com/programming-problem-solving-logbook/rails-multiple-checkboxes-e9c4c7fda356

Comment: Regarding the models, only the names changed slightly. "Response" is data I get back from an API, as well as ContactInfo. Will look into "collection_check_boxes". Thanks for all the suggestions!